How to Execute SetTimeout in C# Blazor
How do you execute something similar to settimeout in C# Blazor as an infinite loop with UI Changes through data manipulation?

@code{

    protected async override void OnInitialized()
    {
        var task = new Task(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    ExternalClassFile.DoWork();
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    this.InvokeAsync(() => this.StateHasChanged());
                }
            });
        task.Start();
        base.OnInitialized();        
    }
}


Just use a System.Threading.Timer - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=net-8.0
